# how to normalize a `scala.reflect.api.Types.Type`

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-macros

How to implement the function `normalize(type: Type): Type` such that:

`A =:= B` if and only if `normalize(A) == normalize(B)` and `normalize(A).hashCode == normalize(B).hashCode`.

In other words, `normalize` must return `equal` results for all equivalent `Type` instances; and not `equal` nor equivalent results for all pair of non equivalent inputs.

There is a deprecated method called `normalize` in the `TypeApi`, but it does not the same.

In my particular case I only need to normalize types that represent a class or a trait (`tpe.typeSymbol.isClass == true`).

**Edit 1:** The fist comment suggests that such a function might not be possible to implement in general. But perhaps it is possible if we add another constraint:
`B` is obtained by navigating from `A`.
In the next example `fooType` would be `A`, and `nextAppliedType` would be `B`:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
sealed trait Foo[V]
case class FooImpl[V](next: Foo[V]) extends Foo[V]

scala> val fooType = typeOf[Foo[Int]]
val fooType: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = Foo[Int]

scala> val nextType = fooType.typeSymbol.asClass.knownDirectSubclasses.iterator.next().asClass.primaryConstructor.typeSignature.paramLists(0)(0).typeSignature
val nextType: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = Foo[V]

scala> val nextAppliedType = appliedType(nextType.typeConstructor, fooType.typeArgs)
val nextAppliedType: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = Foo[Int]

scala> println(fooType =:= nextAppliedType)
true

scala> println(fooType == nextAppliedType)
false
```

Inspecting the `Type` instances with `showRaw` shows why they are not equal (at least when Foo and FooImpl are members of an object, in this example, the `jsfacile.test.RecursionTest` object):

```
scala> showRaw(fooType)
val res2: String = TypeRef(SingleType(SingleType(SingleType(ThisType(<root>), jsfacile), jsfacile.test), jsfacile.test.RecursionTest), jsfacile.test.RecursionTest.Foo, List(TypeRef(ThisType(scala), scala.Int, List())))

scala> showRaw(nextAppliedType)
val res3: String = TypeRef(ThisType(jsfacile.test.RecursionTest), jsfacile.test.RecursionTest.Foo, List(TypeRef(ThisType(scala), scala.Int, List())))
```

The reason I need this is difficult to explain. Let's try:

I am developing [this JSON library](https://github.com/readren/json-facile) which works fine except when there is a recursive type reference. For example:

```
sealed trait Foo[V]
case class FooImpl[V](next: Foo[V]) extends Foo[V]
```

That happens because the parser/appender it uses to parse and format are type classes that are materialized by an implicit macro. And when an implicit parameter is recursive the compiler complains with a divergence error.
I tried to solve that using by-name implicit parameter but it not only didn't solve the recursion problem, but also makes many non recursive algebraic data type to fail.
So, now I am trying to solve this problem by storing the resolved materializations in a map, which also would improve the compilation speed. And that map key is of type `Type`. So I need to normalize the `Type` instances, not only to be usable as key of a map, but also to equalize the values generated from them.

Comment: Why do you think such function is possible? I guess we are not supposed to rely on `equals`/`hashCode` for `Type`s (on contrary to `=:=`). In the deprecation notice for standard `normalize` it's recommended to use `dealias` or `etaExpand` instead. Why are they not enough in your use case? Please provide several examples of input and desirable output for such hypothetical custom function `normalize`.

Comment: Generally this sounds like XY. Please describe what you're actually doing and what you need?

Comment: Your `normalize` looks like selecting a representative in every equivalence class with respect to the relation `=:=` on `Type`s ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice) :) But it's not clear how to prefer a single representative in every equivalence class.

Comment: @DmytroMitin If I understood you well, any equivalence class would be fine. There is no preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I understood you well, any equivalence class would be fine. There is no preference.

I suspect you didn't. At least *"any equivalence class would be fine"*, *"There is no preference"* do not sound good. I'll try to elaborate.

In math there is such construction as factorization. If you have a set `A` and equivalence relation `~` on this set (relation means that for any pair of elements from `A` we know whether they are related `a1 ~ a2` or not, equivalence means symmetricity `a1 ~ a2 => a2 ~ a1`, reflexivity `a ~ a`, transitivity `a1 ~ a2, a2 ~ a3 => a1 ~ a3`) then you can consider the factor-set `A/~` whose elements are all equivalence classes `A/~ = { [a] | a ∈ A}` (the equivalence class

```
[a] = {b ∈ A | b ~ a}
```

of an element `a` is a set consisting of all elements equivalent (i.e. `~`-related) to `a`).

[The axiom of choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice) says that there is a map (function) from `A/~` to `A` i.e. we can select a representative in every equivalence class and in such way form a subset of `A` (this is true if we accept the axiom of choice, if we don't then it's not clear whether we get a set in such way). But even if we accept the axiom of choice and therefore **there is** a function `A/~ -> A` this doesn't mean we can **construct** such function.

[Simple example.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set) Let's consider the set of all real numbers `R` and the following equivalence relation: two real numbers are equivalent `r1 ~ r2` if their difference is a rational number

```
r2 - r1 = p/q ∈ Q
```

(`p`, `q≠0` are arbitrary integers). This is an equivalence relation. So it's known that there is a function selecting a single real number from any equivalence class but how to define this function explicitly for a specific input? For example what is the output of this function for the input being the equivalence class of `0` or `1` or `π` or `e` or `√2` or `log 2`...?

Similarly, `=:=` is an equivalence relation on types, so it's known that there is a function `normalize` (maybe there are even many such functions) selecting a representative in every equivalence class but how to prefer a specific one (how to define or construct the output explicitly for any specific input)?

Regarding your struggle against implicit divergence. It's not necessary that you've selected the best possible approach. Sounds like you're doing some compiler work manually. How do other json libraries solve the issue? For example Circe? Besides by-name implicits `=>` there is also `shapeless.Lazy` / `shapeless.Strict` (not equivalent to by-name implicits). If you have specific question about deriving type classes, overcoming implicit divergence maybe you should start a different question about that?

Regarding your approach with `HashMap` with `Type` keys. I'm still reminding that we're not supposed to rely on `==` for `Type`s, correct comparison is `=:=`. So you should build your `HashMap` using `=:=` rather than `==`. Search at SO for something like: hashmap custom equals.

---

Actually I guess your `normalize` sounds like you want some caching. You should have a type cache. Then if you asked to calculate `normalize(typ)` you should check whether in the cache there is already a `t` such that `t =:= typ`. If so you should return `t`, otherwise you should add `typ` to the cache and return `typ`.

This satisfies your requirement: `A =:= B` if and only if `normalize(A) == normalize(B)` (`normalize(A).hashCode == normalize(B).hashCode` should follow from `normalize(A) == normalize(B)`).

---

Regarding transformation of `fooType` into `nextAppliedType` try

```
def normalize(typ: Type): Type = typ match { 
  case TypeRef(pre, sym, args) =>
    internal.typeRef(internal.thisType(pre.typeSymbol), sym, args) 
}
```

Then `normalize(fooType) == nextAppliedType` should be `true`.

Comment: Your answer is fabulous! I will try to understand the math part tomorrow. 
Regarding the relation between A, B, and the example's `Type` instances, I edited the question to clarify that.

I knew about `shapeless.Lazy` but before copying it I wanted to try solving the recursive problem this other way; which has the advantage (if it works) that also improves compilation speed.

Using a custom equals and hashCode does not work because the values in the map depend on the keys, and I suspect that equivalent but not equal Type instances don't satisfy Liskov principle for the typeChecker.

Comment: @Readren *"Regarding the relation between `A`, `B`, and the example `Type` instances, I edited the question to clarify that."* Ok, so `fooType` is `A`, and `nextAppliedType` is `B`. But what are outputs for `normalize(fooType)`, `normalize(nextAppliedType)` or outputs on any different inputs? There is simple rule in programming. If you can't formulate what your algorithm (program, function) does then most probably you'll not be able to implement it. Sounds not so like you want to implement `normalize` as you want to change `Type` internal behavior.

Comment: @Readren Actually I guess your `normalize` sounds like you want some caching. You should have a type cache. Then if you asked to calculate `normalize(typ)` you should check whether in the cache there is already a `t` such that `t =:= typ`. If so you should return `t`, otherwise you should add `typ` to the cache and return `typ`.

Comment: I did what you suggest (wrapping the keys and reimplement the equals and hashCode) before asking the question. And the compiler changed the complain from divergence to type-check error. So, I suspected that the outcome of operations to equivalent but not equal `Type` instances are different for the type checker. Now I am beginning to discard that idea.

Comment: @Readren So, can `normalize` with caching work for you? (*If you asked to calculate `normalize(typ)` you check whether in the cache there is already a `t` such that `t =:= typ`. If so you return `t`, otherwise you add `typ` to the cache and return `typ`.*) I guess this satisfies your requirement: `A =:= B` if and only if `normalize(A) == normalize(B)` (`normalize(A).hashCode == normalize(B).hashCode` should follow from `normalize(A) == normalize(B)`).

Comment: Ahhh, I understand your cache based normalize now. That is a good and simple answer for this SO question. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks to your answer I just discovered that with the cache I was using to speed up compilation, I was inadvertently normalizing the `Type` instances as well :)

The bad news is that, therefore, the non equality of equivalent `Type` instances was not the cause of the problem I am having.

Comment: @Readren Regarding transformation of `fooType` to `nextAppliedType` try `def normalize(typ: Type): Type = typ match { case TypeRef(pre, sym, args) => internal.typeRef(internal.thisType(pre.typeSymbol), sym, args) }`. Then `normalize(fooType) == nextAppliedType` should be `true`.

Comment: Thank you again. That let's me get rid of a buffer.